# Screenshot of custom view in Android generates blank image

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I have a view `MyCustomView` which extends `FrameLayout`. The view creates image views dynamically within.

```
private void setModel(Model m) {
   for (Element elem : m.getImageElements()) {
       elem.iv = new ImageView();
       addView(elem.iv);
   }

   ...
   // Load images into the image views
   int count = 0;
   for (Element elem : m.getImageElements()) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load("file://" + elem.photo.getLocalUri())
                .skipMemoryCache()
                .noFade()
                .into(elem.iv, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() { 
                        // When all images have been downloaded successfully 
                        if (++count == m.getImageElements().size) {
                            generatePreview(this, m.getId());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }
                });
    }
}

private static Drawable generatePreview(View targetView, int id) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetView.getLayoutParams().width,
                targetView.getLayoutParams().height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        targetView.draw(c);
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdCard, "image-preview" + id + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95,fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am using the above `MyCustomView` inside a `RecyclerView`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder) {
    ...
    holder.mCustomView.setModel(model);
    ...
 }
```

The problem is for some rows the preview image is coming out as blank (transparent) which seems to indicate that during `draw` of  `MyCustomView` in `generatePreview` the images of elements within `MyCustomView` weren't drawn yet even though `Picasso` `onSuccess` got called.

I have tried putting the `generatePreview` block in a `postDelayed` and calling it after `1000 ms` but that also fails for some rows.

Comment: are you sure that the problem is not that your view has a transparent background which is drawn on the canvas? maybe you could try calling first canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE) and then drawing your view on the canvas

Comment: yes, that is what i think - that the images would not have loaded inside the elements in `MyCustomView` which is why I see the transparent image of the view. But my question is then when should i call the `generatePreview` to guarantee the images have been drawn within the view?

Comment: If setting a delay of 1000ms doesnt work i find it hard to believe that the problem is that you need to wait even longer.. i suspect the problem is a different one, maybe something about the way you dynamically create and bind your views, improper recycling or something to that effect